# Convert nested lists to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, purrr, rbind

My goal is to convert the nested lists produced by my code into a dataframe. I have the following which extracts some data from several urls in a loop and stores them in lists.

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

# declare variables
month = c('07','09')
year = c('2022','2023')
day = c('040','050')

# initialize the empty list
final = list()

# perform the loop
for (i in year) {
  for (j in month) {
    for (k in day) {
    
    skip_to_next <- FALSE
    
    url <- paste0('https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI', i, j, k, '.shtml')
    
    Sys.sleep(5)
    game_path <- tryCatch(url |>
                            read_html() |>
                            html_nodes(xpath = '//div[contains(@id, "batting")]') |> 
                            map(\(x) x |> 
                                  as.character() |> 
                                  str_remove_all("<!--|-->") |> 
                                  read_html() |> 
                                  html_table()) |> 
                            unlist(recursive = FALSE), error = function(e) {skip_to_next <<- TRUE} )
    
    if(skip_to_next) {next}
    
    url <- read_html(url)
    
    list_url <- url %>%
      html_nodes(xpath = "//td/a") %>% 
      html_text() 
    
    List_2_letters = as.list(list_url[nchar(list_url) > 5])
    
    game_path <- mapply(cbind, game_path, "Date" = paste(gsub('.{1}$', '', k), j, i, sep = '-'), SIMPLIFY=F)
    
    game_path <- Map(cbind, game_path, "Team" = List_2_letters)
    
    final[[i]][[j]][[k]] <- game_path
    
    }
  }
}
```

I get a bunch of lists that look like the following:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to combine all of the lists that have the `data.frame` values.

I tried all of these:

```
final_2 = map_dfr(final, ~ bind_rows(.x))
final_2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, final))
final_2 <- do.call("rbind", final)
```

But they all just produce 2 lists side-by-side. I am actually quite stuck as to how this can be solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result more easily by not creating a nested list. I refactored your code by first putting the main scraping code in a function for easier debugging and testing. Already in this function I bind the team tables into one dataframe using `dplyr::bind_rows`. The function should also be a bit more efficient as it avoids reading the HTML two times as in your code.

For the loop part I switched to `purrr::map`. To this end create a dataframe  containing the dates and the respective URL. This way you can loop directly over the urls without the need of a nested for loop. As a result you will get a list of dataframes which you can finally bind together by rows.

Finally, note that I dropped `tryCatch` and use `purrr::safely` instead for the error handling.

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

make_url <- function(year, month, day) {
  paste0(
    "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI",
    year, month, day, ".shtml"
  )
}

scrape_table <- function(url) {
  html <- read_html(url)

  nodes <- html |>
    html_elements(xpath = '//div[starts-with(@id, "all_") and contains(@id, "batting")]')

  teams <- html %>%
    html_elements(xpath = "//td/a") %>%
    html_text()

  nodes |>
    purrr::set_names(teams) |>
    purrr::map(\(x) {
      x |>
        as.character() |>
        str_remove_all("<!--|-->") |>
        read_html() |>
        html_table()
    }) |>
    unlist(recursive = FALSE) |>
    dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "Team")
}


# declare variables
month <- c("07", "09")
year <- c("2022")
day <- c("040")

dates <- expand.grid(
  year = year, month = month, day = day
)

urls <- dates |>
  mutate(
    url = make_url(year, month, day),
    date = paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"),
    .keep = "unused"
  )

safe_scrape_table <- purrr::safely(scrape_table)

final <- purrr::map(urls$url, \(url) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  safe_scrape_table(url)
}) |>
  set_names(urls$date)

final <- final |>
  purrr::transpose() |>
  pluck("result") |>
  bind_rows(.id = "Date")

head(final)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 26
#>   Date       Team  Batting    AB     R     H   RBI    BB    SO    PA    BA   OBP
#>   <chr>      <chr> <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2022-07-0… San … Austin…     2     0     0     0     1     1     3 0.243 0.367
#> 2 2022-07-0… San … Mike Y…     2     0     0     0     0     1     2 0.236 0.338
#> 3 2022-07-0… San … Wilmer…     3     1     0     0     0     2     4 0.242 0.331
#> 4 2022-07-0… San … Darin …     2     1     0     0     1     2     4 0.22  0.335
#> 5 2022-07-0… San … Evan L…     3     1     1     0     1     0     4 0.248 0.333
#> 6 2022-07-0… San … LaMont…     4     0     1     2     0     0     4 0.22  0.313
#> # ℹ 14 more variables: SLG <dbl>, OPS <dbl>, Pit <int>, Str <int>, WPA <dbl>,
#> #   aLI <dbl>, `WPA+` <dbl>, `WPA-` <chr>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>,
#> #   PO <int>, A <int>, Details <chr>
```

**EDIT** The issue is that the datatypes of the columns differ from date to date, i.e. for 2022-07-04 the `WPA-` column is read as a `character` as the values include a `%` symbol whereas for 2023-07-04 it contains only a number and hence is read as a `numeric`. To fix that we need do to do some data cleaning before we can bind the tables. The following code splits the steps in parts. First, extract the tables with the result. Then loop over the list of dataframe and convert character columns which should be numerics to numerics using e.g. `readr::parse_number`. After doing so the bind should in principle work. I tested for years 2022 and 2023. But of course is it possible that other issues arise. A more safe option would be to convert all columns to characters. Then bind. Then do the data cleaning afterwards and finally convert the columns to numerics.

```
final_result <- final |>
  purrr::transpose() |>
  pluck("result")

# Data Cleaning
final <- map(
  final_result,
  \(x) {
    x |> 
      mutate(across(!c(Team, Batting, Details) & where(is.character), readr::parse_number))
  }
)

# Bind
final <- final |>
  bind_rows(.id = "Date")
```

Comment: wow thank you so much! This is great! Ultimately I will add multiple days, months and years. I added 2023 to the year variable (`year <- c("2022", "2023")` and when I ran I got this error: `Error in bind_rows():! Can't combine 2022-07-04$WPA- <character> and 2023-07-04$WPA- <double>.`?

Comment: The issue is that the datatypes of the columns differ, i.e. for 2022-07-04 the `WPA-` column is a character as the values include a `%` symbol whereas for 2023-07-04 it is only a number. To fix that we need do to do some data cleaning before we can bind the tables. See my edit which I tested by running the script for both years.

Comment: that's perfect! I know this is not part of the original question, but I mistakenly left out that I also want to create a team variable (the above works for just one team - Arizona - 'ARI'). I attempted by creating a team variable `team = c('ARI', 'WAS')` and I adjusted url to `make_url <- function(team, year, month, day)` and `url = make_url(team, year, month, day),` but I get `Error in map(): no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

Comment: Looks like the URL is wrong. Hence the scraping function returns NULLs. I got the same error because I did a mistake when adding the team. My function: `make_url <- function(team, year, month, day) {
  paste0(
    "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/",
    team, "/", team, year, month, day, ".shtml"
  )
}`

Comment: yes that is what I did also but still get the error? How should this look so that it works smoothly?

Comment: I also added some more days `day <- c('040','050','060')` and get the same error (after using the suggested code in the answer above.

Comment: some lists return `NULL` values, but I thought the scraping function took care of this? It does not allow the full code to run.

Comment: I assume I am not receiving any more responses on this, so for future readers, the initial answer provided does work, however when adding teams as an additional variable, for some reason this seems to result in lists that return `NULL` values.

Comment: Sorry for not responding. No offence meant. Responses sometime simply fall by the wayside. Always try to respond to follow-ups and fix bugs in our replies. However, there are cases where replying via comments reaches its limits. After the third follow-up question at the latest, it is better to simply ask a new question. About your problem. NULL indicates that an error has occurred. If you get NULL for all URLs, then there is a bug/typo in your code. As I said, this happened to me too. And in my case it was a typo in the URL. If you make changes to your code, you need to test it.

Comment: .... On the basis of an individual case (not by running the whole scirpt over and over again). Take a case that has worked so far. Then create the URL for this case with make_url. Then take this URL and call scrape_table. If something goes wrong, then check out what the problem is. What and where you have changed something. Also. As you want to scape a lot of tables, I would suggest to adapt the code to export already finished tables as a csv. This way you don't lose the work already done. And instead of starting from the beginng you could start for the case where something broke.

Comment: I see thank you. I have indeed posted a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77664560/scrape-data-from-site-using-variables-and-functions-and-bind-tables-to-one-dataf

Comment: Just saw it. Will try to check out what's the issue.

Comment: It is definitely not for all urls only when I add the team variable. I changed it to your suggested make_url but still couldn’t get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying all day long but unfortunately I just cannot resolve the issue.