# Scrape data from site using variables and functions and bind tables to one dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rvest

This is a follow up to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657410/convert-nested-lists-to-a-dataframe-in-r).

The code provided was extremely helpful and allowed me to obtain the data I wanted in a faster and more efficient way. However, since running this, I have encountered two issues that I cannot seem to resolve.

The first is, that I wanted to add a team variable to the function provided, so that it would loop through the web pages containing the team name (not just variables for the day, month and year). So I changed this:

```
make_url <- function(year, month, day) {
  paste0(
    'https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI',  
    year, month, day, '.shtml'
  )
}
```

Like so:

```
make_url <- function(**team**, year, month, day) {
  paste0(
    'https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/', team, '/', team, 
    year, month, day, '.shtml'
  )
}
```

And I created a team variable like this:

```
team = c('ARI','WAS')
```

I also adjusted this part to include the team in the function:

```
urls <- dates |>
  mutate(
    url = make_url(year, month, day),
    date = paste(year, month, gsub('.{1}$', '', day), sep = '-'),
    .keep = 'unused'
  )
```

to this:

```
urls <- dates |>
  mutate(
    url = make_url(**team**, year, month, day),
    date = paste(year, month, gsub('.{1}$', '', day), sep = '-'),
    .keep = 'unused'
  )
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't retain the initial data that is scraped, and it seems to overwrite with the last record.

The second issue is that I am now looking to extract the pitching tables (the initial code was to extract the batting tables).

So I changed this part in the `scrape_table` function:

```
nodes <- html |>
    html_elements(xpath = '//div[starts-with(@id, "all_") and contains(@id, "batting")]')
```

To this:

```
nodes <- html |>
    html_elements(xpath = '//div[starts-with(@id, "all_") and contains(@id, "pitching")]')
```

But it just produces a blank table.

My web scraping abilities are unfortunately not that strong, but when I inspected the page it does show the `div-id` containing `all` and `pitching`, so I am stumped as to why it doesn't capture the correct tables?

The full code can be found in the initial question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657410/convert-nested-lists-to-a-dataframe-in-r).

Comment: I adapted the code to include the team and verified that it still works for batting. Then I have had a look pitching. And the issue is that simply replacing batting by pitching in the xpath does not return anything. But as of the moment I wasn't able to figure out how to fix that. Will have a second look later.

Comment: That is great! Yes I found the same thing. Did the code change for when you included the team?

Comment: @stefan was there any luck on your end with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476819/not-able-to-scrape-a-second-table-within-a-page-using-rvest) to your case here is a solution which allows to get all the tables in one go. However, in the code below I retrieve only the batting and the pitching tables. As a result, for each combo of team and date you will now get a list of tables which you have to process and clean separately.

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)

make_url <- function(team, year, month, day) {
  paste0(
    "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/",
    team, "/", team,
    year, month, day, ".shtml"
  )
}

get_tables <- function(html) {
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481001/12993861
  alt_tables <- xml2::xml_find_all(html, "//comment()") %>%
    {
      # Find only commented nodes that contain the regex for html table markup
      raw_parts <- as.character(.[grep("\\</?table", as.character(.))])
      # Remove the comment begin and end tags
      strip_html <- stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(
        raw_parts, c("<\\!--", "-->"), c("", ""),
        vectorize_all = FALSE
      )
      lapply(grep("<table", strip_html, value = TRUE), function(i) {
        read_html(i) |>
          rvest::html_table()
      })
    }

  list(
    batting = list(
      alt_tables[[2]][[1]],
      alt_tables[[3]][[1]]
    ),
    pitching = alt_tables[[4]]
  )
}

scrape_table <- function(url) {
  html <- read_html(url)

  teams <- html %>%
    html_elements(xpath = "//td/a") %>%
    html_text()

  tbls <- get_tables(html)

  tbls <- lapply(tbls, \(x) {
    names(x) <- teams
    x |>
      dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "Team")
  })
}


# declare variables
month <- c("07")
year <- c("2022")
day <- c("040")
team <- c("ARI")

dates <- expand.grid(
  team = team, year = year, month = month, day = day
)

urls <- dates |>
  mutate(
    url = make_url(team, year, month, day),
    team = team,
    date = paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"),
    .keep = "unused"
  )

safe_scrape_table <- purrr::safely(scrape_table)

foo <- purrr::map(urls$url, \(url) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  safe_scrape_table(url)
}) |>
  set_names(paste(urls$team, urls$date, sep = "-"))

final_result <- foo |>
  purrr::transpose() |>
  pluck("result")

final_result
#> $`ARI-2022-07-040`
#> $`ARI-2022-07-040`$batting
#> # A tibble: 35 × 25
#>    Team      Batting    AB     R     H   RBI    BB    SO    PA    BA   OBP   SLG
#>    <chr>     <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 San Fran… Austin…     2     0     0     0     1     1     3 0.243 0.367 0.417
#>  2 San Fran… Mike Y…     2     0     0     0     0     1     2 0.236 0.338 0.412
#>  3 San Fran… Wilmer…     3     1     0     0     0     2     4 0.242 0.331 0.405
#>  4 San Fran… Darin …     2     1     0     0     1     2     4 0.22  0.335 0.344
#>  5 San Fran… Evan L…     3     1     1     0     1     0     4 0.248 0.333 0.473
#>  6 San Fran… LaMont…     4     0     1     2     0     0     4 0.22  0.313 0.366
#>  7 San Fran… Yermin…     4     0     2     0     0     0     4 0.444 0.444 0.667
#>  8 San Fran… David …     4     0     2     1     0     1     4 0.5   0.5   0.75 
#>  9 San Fran… Curt C…     2     0     0     0     0     1     2 0.231 0.325 0.37 
#> 10 San Fran… Austin…     1     0     1     0     0     0     1 0.227 0.292 0.341
#> # ℹ 25 more rows
#> # ℹ 13 more variables: OPS <dbl>, Pit <int>, Str <int>, WPA <dbl>, aLI <dbl>,
#> #   `WPA+` <dbl>, `WPA-` <chr>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>, PO <int>,
#> #   A <int>, Details <chr>
#> 
#> $`ARI-2022-07-040`$pitching
#> # A tibble: 9 × 28
#>   Team      Pitching    IP     H     R    ER    BB    SO    HR   ERA    BF   Pit
#>   <chr>     <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
#> 1 San Fran… Carlos …     5     5     4     4     2     7     0  2.87    22   101
#> 2 San Fran… Tyler R…     1     3     2     2     0     0     0  4.86     6    19
#> 3 San Fran… Maurici…     2     3     2     2     0     3     0  5.4      9    38
#> 4 San Fran… Team To…     8    11     8     8     2    10     0  9       37   158
#> 5 Arizona … Madison…     5     5     3     3     3     4     0  3.74    24   100
#> 6 Arizona … Sean Po…     1     1     0     0     0     0     0  3.04     3    19
#> 7 Arizona … Joe Man…     2     1     0     0     0     4     0  1.13     7    32
#> 8 Arizona … Mark Me…     1     0     0     0     0     0     0  5.27     3    10
#> 9 Arizona … Team To…     9     7     3     3     3     8     0  3       37   161
#> # ℹ 16 more variables: Str <int>, Ctct <int>, StS <int>, StL <int>, GB <int>,
#> #   FB <int>, LD <int>, Unk <int>, GSc <int>, IR <int>, IS <int>, WPA <dbl>,
#> #   aLI <dbl>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>
```

**EDIT** I did some two more fixes but probably not the last needed. (; First, to fix the issue with the `xpath"//td/a"` returning more than two elements I simple pick the last two elements. Second, I added an `if` to check the number of returned tables:

```r
get_tables <- function(html) {
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481001/12993861
  alt_tables <- xml2::xml_find_all(html, "//comment()") %>%
    {
      # Find only commented nodes that contain the regex for html table markup
      raw_parts <- as.character(.[grep("\\</?table", as.character(.))])
      # Remove the comment begin and end tags
      strip_html <- stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(
        raw_parts, c("<\\!--", "-->"), c("", ""),
        vectorize_all = FALSE
      )
      lapply(grep("<table", strip_html, value = TRUE), function(i) {
        read_html(i) |>
          rvest::html_table()
      })
    }

  # Check length of tables list
  if (length(alt_tables) == 6) {
    list(
      batting = list(
        alt_tables[[1]][[1]],
        alt_tables[[2]][[1]]
      ),
      pitching = alt_tables[[3]]
    )
  } else {
    list(
      batting = list(
        alt_tables[[2]][[1]],
        alt_tables[[3]][[1]]
      ),
      pitching = alt_tables[[4]]
    ) 
  }
  
}

scrape_table <- function(url) {
  html <- read_html(url)
  
  teams <- html %>%
    html_elements(xpath = "//td/a") %>%
    html_text()
  
  # Pick last two elements
  teams <- rev(teams)[c(2, 1)]
  
  tbls <- get_tables(html)

  tbls <- lapply(tbls, \(x) {
    names(x) <- teams
    x |>
      dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "Team")
  })
}


# declare variables
month <- c("07", "10")
year <- c("2022", "2023")
day <- c("040", "110")
team <- c("ARI")

dates <- expand.grid(
  team = team, year = year, month = month, day = day
)

urls <- dates |>
  mutate(
    url = make_url(team, year, month, day),
    team = team,
    date = paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"),
    .keep = "unused"
  )

safe_scrape_table <- purrr::safely(scrape_table)

foo <- purrr::map(urls$url, \(url) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  safe_scrape_table(url)
}) |>
  set_names(paste(urls$team, urls$date, sep = "-"))

final_result <- foo |>
  purrr::transpose() |>
  pluck("result")

final_result
#> $`ARI-2022-07-040`
#> $`ARI-2022-07-040`$batting
#> # A tibble: 35 × 25
#>    Team      Batting    AB     R     H   RBI    BB    SO    PA    BA   OBP   SLG
#>    <chr>     <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 San Fran… Austin…     2     0     0     0     1     1     3 0.243 0.367 0.417
#>  2 San Fran… Mike Y…     2     0     0     0     0     1     2 0.236 0.338 0.412
#>  3 San Fran… Wilmer…     3     1     0     0     0     2     4 0.242 0.331 0.405
#>  4 San Fran… Darin …     2     1     0     0     1     2     4 0.22  0.335 0.344
#>  5 San Fran… Evan L…     3     1     1     0     1     0     4 0.248 0.333 0.473
#>  6 San Fran… LaMont…     4     0     1     2     0     0     4 0.22  0.313 0.366
#>  7 San Fran… Yermin…     4     0     2     0     0     0     4 0.444 0.444 0.667
#>  8 San Fran… David …     4     0     2     1     0     1     4 0.5   0.5   0.75 
#>  9 San Fran… Curt C…     2     0     0     0     0     1     2 0.231 0.325 0.37 
#> 10 San Fran… Austin…     1     0     1     0     0     0     1 0.227 0.292 0.341
#> # ℹ 25 more rows
#> # ℹ 13 more variables: OPS <dbl>, Pit <int>, Str <int>, WPA <dbl>, aLI <dbl>,
#> #   `WPA+` <dbl>, `WPA-` <chr>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>, PO <int>,
#> #   A <int>, Details <chr>
#> 
#> $`ARI-2022-07-040`$pitching
#> # A tibble: 9 × 28
#>   Team      Pitching    IP     H     R    ER    BB    SO    HR   ERA    BF   Pit
#>   <chr>     <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
#> 1 San Fran… Carlos …     5     5     4     4     2     7     0  2.87    22   101
#> 2 San Fran… Tyler R…     1     3     2     2     0     0     0  4.86     6    19
#> 3 San Fran… Maurici…     2     3     2     2     0     3     0  5.4      9    38
#> 4 San Fran… Team To…     8    11     8     8     2    10     0  9       37   158
#> 5 Arizona … Madison…     5     5     3     3     3     4     0  3.74    24   100
#> 6 Arizona … Sean Po…     1     1     0     0     0     0     0  3.04     3    19
#> 7 Arizona … Joe Man…     2     1     0     0     0     4     0  1.13     7    32
#> 8 Arizona … Mark Me…     1     0     0     0     0     0     0  5.27     3    10
#> 9 Arizona … Team To…     9     7     3     3     3     8     0  3       37   161
#> # ℹ 16 more variables: Str <int>, Ctct <int>, StS <int>, StL <int>, GB <int>,
#> #   FB <int>, LD <int>, Unk <int>, GSc <int>, IR <int>, IS <int>, WPA <dbl>,
#> #   aLI <dbl>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>
#> 
#> 
#> $`ARI-2023-07-040`
#> $`ARI-2023-07-040`$batting
#> # A tibble: 38 × 25
#>    Team    Batting    AB     R     H   RBI    BB    SO    PA     BA   OBP    SLG
#>    <chr>   <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 New Yo… Brando…     3     1     1     1     2     0     5  0.28  0.375  0.466
#>  2 New Yo… Tommy …     5     0     0     0     0     1     5  0.287 0.354  0.516
#>  3 New Yo… Franci…     3     2     1     1     1     1     5  0.224 0.31   0.448
#>  4 New Yo… Pete A…     5     0     0     0     0     3     5  0.217 0.311  0.51 
#>  5 New Yo… Jeff M…     3     1     1     0     1     1     4  0.259 0.334  0.332
#>  6 New Yo… Starli…     3     1     2     3     1     0     4  0.256 0.309  0.34 
#>  7 New Yo… Daniel…     2     0     0     0     1     0     3  0.206 0.321  0.338
#>  8 New Yo… DJ Ste…     0     1     0     1     0     0     1 NA     0     NA    
#>  9 New Yo… Franci…     4     1     1     2     0     2     4  0.215 0.272  0.471
#> 10 New Yo… Brett …     4     1     2     0     0     1     4  0.249 0.315  0.363
#> # ℹ 28 more rows
#> # ℹ 13 more variables: OPS <dbl>, Pit <int>, Str <int>, WPA <dbl>, aLI <dbl>,
#> #   `WPA+` <dbl>, `WPA-` <dbl>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>, PO <int>,
#> #   A <int>, Details <chr>
#> 
#> $`ARI-2023-07-040`$pitching
#> # A tibble: 12 × 28
#>    Team     Pitching    IP     H     R    ER    BB    SO    HR   ERA    BF   Pit
#>    <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
#>  1 New Yor… Max Sch…   6       5     4     4     2     9     3  4.03    25   101
#>  2 New Yor… Brooks …   1       0     0     0     2     1     0  2.35     5    18
#>  3 New Yor… Adam Ot…   1       1     0     0     0     2     0  3.86     4    19
#>  4 New Yor… Drew Sm…   0.2     1     1     1     1     0     0  4.45     4    12
#>  5 New Yor… David R…   0.1     1     0     0     1     0     0  1.93     3     9
#>  6 New Yor… Team To…   9       8     5     5     6    12     3  5       41   159
#>  7 Arizona… Zach Da…   5.2     5     4     4     2     6     2  6.52    22    94
#>  8 Arizona… Kyle Ne…   0.1     0     0     0     0     0     0  2.81     1     3
#>  9 Arizona… Miguel …   1       1     2     2     2     1     1  3.67     6    32
#> 10 Arizona… Austin …   0.1     0     1     1     2     1     0  4.09     4    19
#> 11 Arizona… José Ru…   1.2     2     1     1     0     1     0  5.4      7    24
#> 12 Arizona… Team To…   9       8     8     8     6     9     3  8       40   172
#> # ℹ 16 more variables: Str <int>, Ctct <int>, StS <int>, StL <int>, GB <int>,
#> #   FB <int>, LD <int>, Unk <int>, GSc <int>, IR <int>, IS <int>, WPA <dbl>,
#> #   aLI <dbl>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>
#> 
#> 
#> $`ARI-2022-10-040`
#> NULL
#> 
#> $`ARI-2023-10-040`
#> NULL
#> 
#> $`ARI-2022-07-110`
#> NULL
#> 
#> $`ARI-2023-07-110`
#> NULL
#> 
#> $`ARI-2022-10-110`
#> NULL
#> 
#> $`ARI-2023-10-110`
#> $`ARI-2023-10-110`$batting
#> # A tibble: 42 × 25
#>    Team      Batting    AB     R     H   RBI    BB    SO    PA    BA   OBP   SLG
#>    <chr>     <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Los Ange… Mookie…     4     0     0     0     0     1     4 0     0.083 0    
#>  2 Los Ange… Freddi…     4     0     0     0     0     1     4 0.1   0.25  0.1  
#>  3 Los Ange… J.D. M…     4     0     0     0     0     2     4 0.2   0.333 0.5  
#>  4 Los Ange… Max Mu…     4     1     1     0     0     2     4 0.182 0.25  0.182
#>  5 Los Ange… Will S…     4     1     3     0     0     0     4 0.417 0.417 0.667
#>  6 Los Ange… Jason …     1     0     0     0     0     0     1 0     0     0    
#>  7 Los Ange… Chris …     3     0     1     1     0     1     3 0.167 0.286 0.167
#>  8 Los Ange… Enriqu…     4     0     2     1     0     0     4 0.375 0.375 0.375
#>  9 Los Ange… David …     2     0     0     0     0     0     2 0.167 0.167 0.333
#> 10 Los Ange… Austin…     1     0     0     0     0     0     1 0     0     0    
#> # ℹ 32 more rows
#> # ℹ 13 more variables: OPS <dbl>, Pit <int>, Str <int>, WPA <dbl>, aLI <dbl>,
#> #   `WPA+` <dbl>, `WPA-` <dbl>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>, PO <int>,
#> #   A <int>, Details <chr>
#> 
#> $`ARI-2023-10-110`$pitching
#> # A tibble: 14 × 28
#>    Team     Pitching    IP     H     R    ER    BB    SO    HR   ERA    BF   Pit
#>    <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
#>  1 Los Ang… Lance L…   2.2     6     4     4     0     1     4 13.5     14    48
#>  2 Los Ang… Caleb F…   1.1     0     0     0     1     2     0  0        5    18
#>  3 Los Ang… Michael…   1       0     0     0     2     1     0  4.5      5    22
#>  4 Los Ang… Alex Ve…   1       0     0     0     0     1     0  4.5      3    18
#>  5 Los Ang… Brusdar…   1       1     0     0     0     1     0  0        3    11
#>  6 Los Ang… Evan Ph…   1       1     0     0     0     1     0  0        5    19
#>  7 Los Ang… Team To…   8       8     4     4     3     7     4  4.5     35   136
#>  8 Arizona… Brandon…   4.1     2     0     0     0     2     0  3.86    14    42
#>  9 Arizona… Joe Man…   1.1     0     0     0     0     1     0  0        4    14
#> 10 Arizona… Ryan Th…   1       4     2     2     0     1     0  3.6      7    23
#> 11 Arizona… Andrew …   0.1     0     0     0     0     0     0  0        1     1
#> 12 Arizona… Kevin G…   1       0     0     0     1     2     0  0        4    17
#> 13 Arizona… Paul Se…   1       1     0     0     0     1     0  0        4    15
#> 14 Arizona… Team To…   9       7     2     2     1     7     0  2       34   112
#> # ℹ 16 more variables: Str <int>, Ctct <int>, StS <int>, StL <int>, GB <int>,
#> #   FB <int>, LD <int>, Unk <int>, GSc <int>, IR <int>, IS <int>, WPA <dbl>,
#> #   aLI <dbl>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>
```

Comment: thank you! This appears to be providing the desired results.

Comment: with this solution, I still have the same issue with the datatypes of the columns differing from date to date, i.e. for 2022-07-04 the WPA- column is read as a character as the values include a % symbol whereas for 2023-07-04 it contains only a number and hence is read as a numeric. I tried using `mutate(across(!c(Team, Batting, Details) & where(is.character), readr::parse_number))` as in your previous response but this did not work. Is there a way this can be done within the answer above?

Comment: can you also explain why no post season data is picked up? I tried several variables, e.g ARI in 2023, I used `month <- c("10"), year <- c("2023"), day <- c("110")` for the game played on that day. The url is correct `https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI202310110.shtml` but the table is showing as empty.

Comment: Yup. The structure of the page is differs slightly from the one I used as example in the script (A first guess: Because of the different year). First issue is that the code will not pick the right tables. Second issue and the one which breaks the code is that the xpath = "//td/a" matches more elements not just the two team names. As a result we have a vector of 11 names but only a list of two elements. You have to adapt the code to account for that, e.g. if the year is the reason for that, then for year 2022 use the code in the answer, but use the adapted code for year 2023.

Comment: ok that is most helpful. I have seen where it breaks as it matches more elements. I can get the correct teams by adapting the code, but I cannot for the life of me work out how it picks the wrong tables? The `scrape_table` function returns the correct tables, but then the `tbl_scrape` using `purrr::map` returns an incorrect pitching table. Are you able to provide an example of how that script should look?

Comment: would you suggest I post a follow up question with these issues?

Comment: See my edit. I just added two fixes to deal with both issues. But be aware that you may encounter other issues.

Comment: much appreciated! In the end I just needed an `IF` statement to pull the different tables, as I already worked out how to retrieve the last 2 elements in the names! What do you mean by "but probably not the last needed"?

Comment: (: That was only meant as a word of caution. After all, this was the second or third fix. Therefore, I would assume that it is likely that further issues will occur that are not foreseeable.